# vscode Make snippet first choice when hitting tab

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I wrote my own simple snippet for const in javascript:

`const` should trigger `const ${1} = ${0};`

and it works very well. However, when I enter const and the available options pop open in the menu, I do not get the snippet as a first, but as a second option which means I first need to go down one step with an arrow and then I can select it with `tab`.

I'm coming from vim where evert keystroke matters in terms of productivity and this is annoying me so much that I decided to write here no stackoverflow. Does anyone know how I can make it the first option if it matches the snippet?

Also, does anyone know what the first option actually means?

[image: const Snippet vscode]

Comment: Maybe you should use an abbreviation of  `const` like `co` for the trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `settings.json`

```json
{
    "typescript.useCodeSnippetsOnMethodSuggest": true,
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "editor.tabCompletion": true
}
```

By default, `editor.snippetSuggestions` is `bottom` so setting it to `top` wil show it at top.

Note: both standard and your custom snippets will be show in suggestion.if you want your snippet to go above the standard - you can change description so that it sorts at top.

You can see about it [here(github link)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10565#issuecomment-317319434)